# Returning values in C

Tags: c, function, return

Ok I am just completely stuck on my homework and my brain is not working right now. I'm still not that good of a programmer so I need help on wondering what's happening in the code how I can fix them.

I am have trouble understanding using pointers.

I'm not sure if I am doing it right of trying to return values.
There is going to be another program that I have to code to actually use these functions but I was given this one to work on first.

For the Add Function, I am trying to make the item point to each parameter to get the data.

For the AddItem Function, I am trying to have a new item point to item from the Add Function and get that data.

Contain Function(Still working on): I have to take a parameter from AddItem Function. Return true if item exists, false if doesn't.

Get Function(Still working on): Same parameter as Contain function. Return pointer of the found item, or NULL if item not found.

Data.h

```
  #ifndef DATA_H_
  #define DATA_H_

  /*
   * Database Struct
   */
    typedef struct
    {
       /*char *array[10];*/
        Iteminfo *itemdata;
        int counter;
    }databaseinfo;

    /*
     * Item Struct
     */
     typedef struct
     {
     int IDnum;
      double price;
     char * Name;
     }Iteminfo;

    /*
     * Prototypes
      */
         char DatabaseManage();
         int Add();
         char AddItem();
         int Contains();
         int Get();

         #endif /* DATA_H_ */
```

DatabaseManage.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Data.h"

   /*
    * Constructor Function
    * @Parameters databaseinfo, count
    * Creates and returns the database
    */
     databaseinfo constructor(Iteminfo *itemdata, int counter)
     {
       databaseinfo *newdb = malloc(sizeof(databaseinfo));
       return constructor;

     }
     /*
    * Add Function
    * @Parameters Iteminfo, IDnum, price, Name
    *  Adds an item to the database
    */
       int Add(Iteminfo *item, int IDnum, double price, char * Name)
       {
      item->IDnum = IDnum;
      item->price = price;
      item->Name = Name;

      return item;
   }

   /*
    * AddItem Function
    * @Parameters Iteminfo
    * Copies item to database
    */
    char AddItem(Iteminfo *item, char * newItem)
     {
     newitem->item = item;
      return copyitem;

     }

    /*
     * Contains Function
     * @Parameter
     * Returns if the item exists or not in the database
     */
    int Contains(void)
    {

    }

    /*
     * Get Function
     * @Parameters
     * Returns the pointer of the item from the database
     */
     int get(void)
     {

     }
```

Comment: What is the question??

Comment: @KarthikT wants us to do their functions

Comment: I guess it is more of syntax related if I'm doing things right. If I am using the pointers right to return the values, I'm sort of in a mess right now of trying to figure out what to do here.

Comment: @user2031589 well.. `int*` to return `int` pointer, and `bool` to return boolean (true/false) values

Comment: a tip i can give is to read form right to left and thats how you know the type. example: int* x; reading from left to right: i have an int which is a pointer. reading from right to left: i have a pointer for int.

Comment: try posting code that (a) stands a chance of compiling, and (b) isn't just a bunch of stubs. `AddItem()` for example, takes two parameters, dereferences an undeclared variable, then returns another undeclared variable. The order of your `Iteminfo` and `databaseinfo` struct decls will not compile as written. v2c.

Answer (score 1):

The first of all:

```
 databaseinfo constructor(Iteminfo *itemdata, int counter)
 {
   databaseinfo *newdb = malloc(sizeof(databaseinfo));
   return constructor;
 }
```

When you write return in the function is supposed to return the value if it is not `void` function.

So it should be:

```
 databaseinfo* constructor(Iteminfo *itemdata, int counter)
 {
   databaseinfo *newdb = (databaseinfo*)malloc(sizeof(databaseinfo));
   // your code here for data initialization
   return newdb; 
 }
```

In this case the function will return you a pointer to allocated memory.

Ans so on.